# For a simple stroller, the cloth seat can be easily removed from the frame. Would you say "to take the cloth seat off or out of the frame"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

For a simple stroller, the cloth seat can be easily removed from the frame.

As shown in the picture, the cloth seat has 2 long holes on its sides. To put the stroller together, people will slide the 2 holes **onto** the 2 sticks of the frame.

[image]

Would you say "**to take the cloth seat off or out of the frame**"?

I think it would be "**off**" because we put the seat "**on**" the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be either. If the frame "surrounds" the cloth and holds it tightly, then "out of" would make more sense.  But here the cloth is more or less laid on the frame, the frame doesn't hold it tightly, so "take the seat off the frame" seems to match the meaning better.

Comment: Yes. Off sounds better than 'out of'

Answer (score 2):

Neither sounds natural.

The most natural phrasing is exactly what you already *did* use (perhaps unconsciously) when asking the question:

**remove from**

> The cloth seat can be easily *removed from* the frame.

---

In contrast, the cloth seat would have been **put into** or **attached to** the frame.

Comment: Why "the cloth seat would have been put into the frame"? The cloth seat has holes on the sides would have been put ON / ONTO the frame.

Comment: @Tom Look at the picture. The cloth is not *on top of* the frame. It's *inside* the frame. The frame is *around* the cloth, not *underneath* it. But as I said, you can also just say *attached to*.

Comment: But why we say "put the Tshirt on" even the Tshirt is not on top of our head. Do you see the similarity, "put the Tshirt on" and "put the cloth seat on the frame"?

Comment: Sometimes, my child yanks the seat so hard that it "COMES OFF THE FRAME", right?  Imagine, the frame is a human and the clothe seat is a piece of clothes.

Comment: *It comes **out of** the frame* would be more natural in the context of the specific child seat in the picture and yanking the cover. Context is ***essential***. The prepositions used when talking about a human frame and clothing is something entirely different. In *that* context, the prepositions change, and *off* actually would be appropriate.